# How to add hours to string in linux?

Tags: linux, date, date-format, rhel

I have a question about formating date.

Is there any way to add some specific hours or minutes to date. for example I would assign date from `who -b` command to variable and then add 3 hours to this variable.

Is this possible by some command or is it more tricky?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this can make it. Note the use of `date -d" some date "` and then the fact that we do `+ 3 hours`.

`tr -s ' '` squeezes the spaces. `cut -d ' ' -f4-` gets from the 4th field up to the end.

```
$ who -b
         system boot  2013-09-13 10:19
$ date -d"$(who -b | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f4-) +3 hours"
Fri Sep 13 10:19:00 CEST 2013
```